# How can ORDER BY clause sort the records starting from 1 instead of 0

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

In a typical ORDER BY clasue, if a column having only numerical values. then, how is it possible to make a query so that the result would sort the numbers from 1 to infinity and rest zeroes and negative numbers come at last.

I have this table : TABLEONE

```
col1 | col2
0    | Zero
5    | Five
-2   | NA
1    | One
2    | Two
7    | NA
```

if I pass this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEONE ORDER BY col1;
```

The rows are sorting in this order

```
-2, 0, 1, 2, 5, 7
```

What I want is :

```
1, 2, 5, 7, 0, -2, -4 ... etc..
```

Is it possible to alter our existing query to get that result. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    T
ORDER BY SIGN(Col1) DESC, ABS(Col1);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63b80/1)**

Comment: Clever! Zero is a special case and has `0` as sign.

Comment: Now, that's the perfect answer for this question. I just checked the Fiddle, it's working exactly the same way as I was looking for it. Thanks GarethD

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLEONE 
ORDER BY (col1 > 0) DESC, ABS(col1) ASC;
```